# Rename tag [visual-editor] to [mediawiki-visualeditor]?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

Only a fraction of the [visual-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-editor) questions seem to be actually about [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor) the software (which, according to its description, the tag is supposed to denote), and all of those questions also have the `mediawiki` tag. Even though VisualEditor is technically an independent piece of software and there are a few real-world cases of it being used independently, it is still predominantly used as a MediaWiki composent, so maybe renaming the tag to `mediawiki-visualeditor` could reduce the confusion?